# Rapid publishing experiment

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint

In 2015 or 2016, there was an experiment by a group of post-docs and graduate students to ideate, research, and publish a scientific article (on a pre-print site like arxiv.org) in 24 hours. The topic was something to do with social networks, but the speed of writing the paper was the main point. Can anyone point me to that paper? A group I'm in is going to attempt a similar experiment. Thanks!

Comment: There is a well-known paper in my field that is 1 page long and was written in 1 day. (Including the research.) OK, the currently available version is 2 pages long.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you might be thinking of the "72 Hours of Science" experiment, which resulted in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02096). This was done at the Santa Fe Institute, and you can find the news release describing the project [here](https://www.santafe.edu/news-center/news/72-hours-science-announce). As they say, finalizing the topic and organizing tasks took up pretty much the first 24 hours, so also fitting the research and write-up into a mere 24 hours sounds rather difficult.

There was a second [72 Hours of Science](https://www.santafe.edu/news-center/news/marathon-science-event-72hs-explores-trends-world-records) in 2017, resulting in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04353). The project has also inspired the [Complexity72h](https://complexity72h.weebly.com/) workshop, and possibly other follow-ups.